Upload image Intervention Image v3.7
The error Unable to decode input is occurred at the line $image = $manager->read($file);. Here is my code:
Controller
public function upload(Request $request)
    {
        try {
            $filePath = 'banners/';

            if (app()->environment('local')) {
                $filePath = 'local/' . $filePath;
            }

            $file = ImageService::processImage($request->file('file'), $filePath, 1920, 1080);

            return response()->json([
                'message' => 'Banner uploaded successfully',
                'url' => $file
            ]);

        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            return response()->json([
                'message' => 'An error occurred',
                'detail' => $e->getMessage()
            ]);
        }
    }

ImageService
public static function processImage($file, $path, int $width = NULL, int $height = NULL)
    {
        try {
            $filePath = $path . auth()->id() . '_' . Str::random(40) . '_' . time() . '.jpg';
            $manager = new ImageManager(Driver::class);

            // $image = $manager->read('file url') -> this work normally

            // A problem here: Unable to decode input
            $image   = $manager->read($file);

            if ($file->getSize() > self::$maxSize || $width || $height) {
                if ($width && ! $height) {
                    $image->resize(width: $width);
                } elseif (! $width && $height) {
                    $image->resize(height: $height);
                } else {
                    $image->resize($width ?? self::$defaultWidth, $height ?? self::$defaultHeight);
                }
            }
            $encoded = $image->encode(new JpegEncoder(quality: 75));
            Storage::put($filePath, $encoded, 'public');

            return $filePath;
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            dd($e->getMessage());
            Log::info('PROCESS IMAGE ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage());
        }
    }

Someone can explain to me how to upload with Intervention Image (v3.7)

specify FilePathImageDecoder::class as second paramter as: $manager->read($file, FilePathImageDecoder::class); If still doesn't work try initializing the imagemanager class without driver class: new ImageManager();.  Also, worth trying using $manager->make($file->getRealPath()); instead of $manager->make($file);

It not work, still have the problem unable to decode input

new ImageManager() expected 1 argument Driver. I was trying using $manager->make($file->getRealPath()); before and not work too

can we see your form? or how you upload the 'file'?

Did you manage to solve this? I have the same problem and I'm struggling a lot with this
